# How do I ignore error on "git pull" about the local changes would be overwritten by merge?

Tags: git

How do I ignore the following error message on git pull? 0
We are working on the team, I install Owl carousel and It's working fine on my computer and also It's working fine on my other 2 member's computers also after pushing on Github. But 3rd person trying to pull from the main branch as 2 people.

Comment: 3rd person needs to commit or stash his changes before pulling new changes.

Comment: Rather to *ignore* the error, read its error message. The way to resolve this is described here. (as Aqib rightfully hinted at above)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ignore+error+local+changes+would+be+overwritten+by+merge

Answer (score 1):

The third person either needs to commit their changes (to save them) or stash them (delete all changes since last commit) and then git pull will work for them.